# Выпадающий список 10 000 городов с поиском

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, sql-server

Я только начинаю создавать приложения на Django. 
Моё приложение работает в связке с сервером MS SQL sever.

Цель: пользователь будет вводить название города, должна выпадать подсказка в виде городов из базы данных. Т.к. городов очень много, через HTML теги их вносить нецелесообразно..

Какое решение может мне подойти?

Comment: про jquery autocomplete почитайде доки, там примеры есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью `ajax` отправляешь запрос с поисковой строкой на сервер. А там уже ищешь города в своей таблице. Ставишь ограничение на количество выдаваемых городов:

```
City.objects.filter(title__icontains=city).all()[:10]
```

Далее возвращаешь клиенту в виде `json` и обрабатываешь результат там(помещаешь в блок, селект или еще куда).

Comment: Select2 Autocomplete поможет с JS частью

Comment: Спасибо! А есть ли пример - как результат запроса собрать в JSON?